# How to reboot the machine when it hangs?

Tags: scripting

I would like to know how I can detect when my machine hangs. Let me explain: I always need to run several C programs on my machines (Ubuntu 14.04, 15.04 and 15.10). These programs often hang after a while so I need to detect when the machine does not respond in order to be able to reboot it.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is your limit for when your computer 'hangs'?
Is it when your actions don't get response in 10 seconds, or when all your cores are 100% busy with an infinite loop?

Comment: How do you access these machines? Do you manage them remotely or are you physically there? Do you have `ssh` access? What happens when they hang? Is the whole system frozen or do your C programs crash but the machine is OK? Would using `ping` be an option? Please [edit] and add some more detail. (Si te cuesta escribir en ingles, no te preocupes, pásalo por Google Translate y te lo arreglo yo).

Comment: Possibly related: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/watchdog/watchdog-api.txt

Comment: Perhaps I say something stupid but why you don't look into the reason of why 'several C programs' hang? Otherwise you treat the symptoms and not the actual cause.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the short information, so im access to my machine trough ssh by another computer, and with another computer i do ping to the ip of my third computer , let me explain on this way  :                                                      computer a = is used for access trough ssh                                                            computer b = is used to do ping to my third computer                                     computer c = is the computer where it run the C programs                              so when the ping on the computer b does not respond usually the computer c

Comment: get hangs, and like the computer C is no close to me, i need to know when the computer hangs in order to be able to restart it, to thereby when the computer reboot and enter again to ubuntu, my script can continue with the execution of C programs, but in fact i dont know the reason which causes that the computer C hangs, in fact all my programs it ran over tty1

Answer (score 3):

One options is to use a watchdog to monitor your processes.  See, for example, http://www.jann.cc/2013/02/02/linux_watchdog.html.  The watchdog will automatically cause your system to reboot if it's not kicked every once in a while.  If you have multiple processes that need monitoring, you can configure a watchdog daemon to monitor them.